# Javascript selectors: reference selected item in child function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with ~50 inputs. I've initialized them all with a single class-selector

```html
<input class="common-class" id="firstname" value="Some data">
<input class="common-class" id="lastname" value="Some data">
```

I have an arbitrary plugin (redactor) that will perform actions on the contents. I need to know which input was touched.

```js
function arbitraryPluginFunction(input) {
    /*Plugin doing whatever it has to do */
    input.callback();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".common-class").arbitraryPluginFunction({
        initsetting1: "sample",
        initsetting2: "sample",
        callback: function() {
            console.log("You changed : " + $(this).attr("id"));
        },
    });

});
```

Note the error in my sample because $(this).attr() refers to the object being passed into the plugin. I have an inelegant workaround using $.each, but wondering if there's some proper way.

*** Edit *** Here's something closer to the actual call. I removed redactor from my question to simplyfy

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".common-class").redactor({
    changeCallback: function() {
      console.log("You changed : " + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: For clarity, the actual call would look more like:

$(".common-class").redactor({
        initsetting1: "sample",
        initsetting2: "sample",
        callback: function() {
            console.log("You changed : " + $(this).attr("id"));
        },
});

Comment: How does the plugin call the `callback()` function? It needs to use `.call()` or `.apply()` so it can pass the selected element as `this` context.

Comment: *"I have an inelegant workaround using $.each,..."*: why do think that is not elegant? It is the way to do it actually.

Comment: This seems to be bound to `change` event. You could add the `event` parameter and then use `$(event.target)` as a more specific element than `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you can pass a selector to a jquery function and it will apply that function to all of the matching elements.

Then you create your funtion like **$.fn.redactor** and in the function **$(this)** will correspond to the selected element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.redactor = function(p){
   $(this).on("input",function(){
      p.changeCallback($(this).attr("id"));
   });
}

  $(".common-class").redactor({
    changeCallback: function(id) {
      console.log("You changed : " + id);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="common-class" id="firstname" value="Some data">
<input class="common-class" id="lastname" value="Some data">
```